# Copying newer files only

Tags: files, directory, cp, timestamps

I have a simple shell script. What i'd like to do, is copy the files in `/home/imp/imp/msgs/` to `/home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/`, but only if they are newer in the source directory than the destination directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.MIX /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/
cp /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.BRD /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/
```

I tried `cp -u`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Related (just for reference) [Copying files to a temporary directory, then restoring those files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352540/copying-files-to-a-temporary-directory-then-restoring-those-files)

Answer (score 4):

You can use rsync with the pattern `*.MIX` and `*.BRD`, e.g

```
rsync -avm --include='*.MIX' --include='*.BRD' --exclude='*' /home/imp/imp/msgs/ /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `cp -p` to retain timestamps. Otherwise you can't​ usefully compare them next time.

```
cp -pu /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.MIX /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/
cp -pu /home/imp/imp/msgs/*.BRD /home/imp/imp/msgs/bak/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Make

Here we generate Makefile dynamically using a heredoc and run the dynamic Makefile to accomplish the `copy`

```
cat - <<\CODE | make -f - SRCDIR="/home/imp/imp/msgs" XN="BRD MIX"
.PHONY: all
all: $(foreach i,$(foreach j,$(XN),$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$j)),$(addprefix $(join $(dir $i),bak/),$(notdir $i)))
cprule = $(SRCDIR)/bak/%.$1: $(SRCDIR)/%.$1; /bin/cp -p "$$^" "$$@"
$(foreach i,$(XN),$(eval $(call cprule,$i)))
CODE
```

## Bash

```
SRCDIR="/home/imp/imp/msgs"
for src in "$SRCDIR"/*.MIX "$SRCDIR"/*.BRD
do
   dest=${src%/*}/bak/${src##*/}
   if [ ! -e "$dest" ] || [ "$src" -nt "$dest" ]
   then
      /bin/cp -p "$src" "$dest"
   fi
done
```